# create method channel after upgrading flutter- can not resolve method getFlutterView()

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-channel

i was using native android method in my flutter app using documentation which said use

```
MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler...
```

but after upgrading flutter the `MethodChannel` function does not require `flutterView` and
there is no `flutterView` anymore.

```
can not resolve method getFlutterView()
```

i think there should be a new tutorial for creating channel

instead it needs some `BinaryMessenger` which i don't know what to give instead.

this is the old code which is not working anymore:

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
private static final String CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                    // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
                    // TODO
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Replace `getFlutterView()` with `getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger()`.

You don't actually need the `.getBinaryMessenger()` as `DartExecutor` implements `BinaryMessenger` itself (by just forwarding), but I think it's more correct to specify the messenger.

Comment: well it worked fine but i guess there was some changes in method implementation too , there is no MethodCallHandler() and onMethodCall() i guess.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thanks a lot! +1

Comment: Is it possible to get FlutterEngine and then the BinaryMessenger in an activity extending `YouTubeBaseActivity` rather than `FlutterActivity`?

Comment: cannot resolve getFlutterEngine(). I'm using kotlin BTW.

Answer (score 6):

Simply add this method to your class:

```
BinaryMessenger getFlutterView(){
    return getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger();
}
```

And then optionally replace all ( Refactor > Rename ) "getFlutterView" to "getBinaryMessenger" to have a more readable code:

```
BinaryMessenger getBinaryMessenger(){
    return getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove this `import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;`

Add this import `io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;`

Worked for Me

Comment: According to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects you are encouraged to use embedding classes

Comment: I won't suggest using this. It is not used anymore, after flutter 1.12 embedded package is used.

Answer (score 1):

I spent days trying to figure out how to add a Flutter UI to my existing Android App. The biggest challenge was getting the MethodChannel to work with FlutterActivity being called from MainActivity. I know this is a little different than the question asked here, but this post was returned when I did searches for 'Android FlutterActivity MethodChannel'. After going though many resources on how to do this, I finally found my solution here:
 https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/add_to_app/android_using_plugin/app/src/main/java/dev/flutter/example/androidusingplugin

Initially, in Android Studio, with the existing app opened, I tapped File, New, New Module, Flutter Module. I received an error and had to perform manual steps.

My objective is to launch FlutterActivity (opens main.dart in the flutter_module) in MainActivity - onCreate, then develop Flutter 'screens' leveraging as much native Flutter code as possible, with limited Platform calls using the MethodChannel. As I develop replacement Flutter code, I will continue to comment out the existing Android Code.

Here is what finally worked for me:

## ../App_Project/Android/Existing_Android_App/settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))
evaluate(new File(settingsDir.parentFile, '../flutter_module/.android/include_flutter.groovy'))
include ':flutter_module’
project(':flutter_module’).projectDir = new File('../../flutter_module’)
rootProject.name=‘existing_android_app’
```

## ../App_Project/Android/Existing_Android_App/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
…
    implementation project(':flutter')
}
```

## ../App_Project/Android/Existing_Android_App/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

## ../App_Project/Android/Existing_Android_App/app/src/main/java/com/existing_android_app/MainActivity.java

```
package com.existing_android_app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineCache;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String ENGINE_ID = "1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FlutterEngine flutterEngine = new FlutterEngine(this);
        flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().executeDartEntrypoint(DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault());

        FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().put(ENGINE_ID, flutterEngine);

        MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor(), "com.existing_android_app/myMethodChannel");

        channel.setMethodCallHandler(
                new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull MethodChannel.Result result) {
                        String url = call.argument("url");
                        if (call.method.equals("openBrowser")) {
                            openBrowser(url);
                        } 
                          else {
                            result.notImplemented();
                        }
                    }
                });

        startActivity(FlutterActivity.withCachedEngine(ENGINE_ID).build(this));
    }

    void openBrowser(String url) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

## ../App_Project/flutter_module/lib/home_page.dart

```
class AppHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<AppHomePage> {

  static const platform = const MethodChannel(‘com.existing_android_app/myMethodChannel’);

  Future<void> _openBrowser() async {
    try {
      final int result = await platform.invokeMethod('openBrowser', <String, String> { 'url': "http://bing.com” });
    }
    catch (e) {
      print('***** _openBrowser error: ' + e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              label: Text('Search',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
              onPressed: () {  _openBrowser(); },
            ) // RaisedButton.icon
          ], // Widget
        ) // Column
      ) // Scaffold
    ); // SafeArea
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `flutterEngine?.dartExecutor!!.binaryMessenger` in that `getFlutterView()`